# PHP generated CSS Dropdown with a:hover icons

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, navbar

Okay, so I wrote this dropdown script for a website, but I couldn't think of a way of getting the icons to work in the way they do using modern standards and I'm aware that the way I've done it at the moment is pretty poor practise.

What I've done is a normal CSS Dropdown Navbar, but put a table in the block  element. Thus allowing me to control the opacity of the icon using CSS:

```
ul.Nav li a img {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

ul.Nav li a:hover img {
    opacity:1;
}
```

This doesn't work in old versions of IE and actually breaks the hyperlinks so users can't navigate. The site works fine in Chrome and Firefox and you can view the webpage [here](http://www.modgaji.co.za/en)

This is my HTML/PHP code:

```
<ul class="Nav">
    <?php 
      for ($i = 0; $i < $numititles; $i++) {
        echo "<li><a ";
        if ($i == 0) {echo "style='border:none;width:".$navbutwidth."px;' ";}
                    echo "href='".$titles[$i][0][1]."'>"
                            ."<table style='padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;width:100%;'><tr><td>"
                            .       $titles[$i][0][0]
                            ."</td><td style='padding-right:15px;width:20px;'>"
                            ."  <img src='/i/paw.png' style='width:20px;' alt='' />"
                            ."</td></tr></table></a>";
                    $numjtitles = count($titles[$i]);
                    if ($numjtitles > 1) {
                        echo "<ul>";
                        for ($j = 1; $j < $numjtitles; $j++) {
                            echo "<li><a ";
                            if ($i == 0) {echo "style='border:none;' ";}
                            echo "href='".$titles[$i][$j][1]."'>"
                                    ."<table style='padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;width:100%;'><tr><td>"
                                    .$titles[$i][$j][0]
                                    ."</td><td style='padding-right:15px;width:20px;'>"
                                    ."  <img src='/i/paw.png' style='width:20px;' alt='' />"
                                    ."</td></tr></table></a></li>";
                        }
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                    echo "</li>";
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
```

..and here's my full CSS for the dropdown menu:

```
    ul.Nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:auto;
    z-index:80;
}

ul.Nav li {
    float:left;
}

ul.Nav li a {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#FFF;
    width:<?php echo ($navbutwidth-1); ?>px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-left:1px Solid #FFC;
}

ul.Nav li a table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

ul.Nav li a tr {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#960;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

ul.Nav li a tr:hover {
    background-color:#C93;
}

ul.Nav li a td {
    padding-left:15px;
}

ul.Nav li a img {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

ul.Nav li a:hover img {
    opacity:1;
}

ul.Nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    text-align:left;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    min-width:9.3ex;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: left 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: left 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: left 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: left 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: left 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

ul.Nav ul li {
    float:none;
    border-top:1px Solid #FFF;
}

ul.Nav ul a {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.Nav li:hover ul{
    left:inherit;
    opacity:1;
}
ul.Nav li:hover a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.Nav li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.Nav li:hover ul li a:hover{

}
```

What's the best way to achieve this.. I want to keep the paws that appear when you hover over the navigation buttons if possible!

Comment: Try to validate your code as XHTML1.1/CSS2 compatible. I would say the markup is not right and there are better solutions to your problem.

Comment: You would do better if you used html with pieces of PHP, instead of creating a long string of of html.

Comment: Why don't u just use nested list instead of tables ? SEO++;

Comment: BTW, you have done a nice menu!

Comment: DarkBee. What exactly do you mean by nested lists? Can you show me an example? and thank you DontVoteMeDown
@MightyPork.. I have considered this after looking at the amount of code that is HTML rather than PHP, but I seem to remember I did it like that for a reason.. Not sure what that reason is anymore?

Comment: He is using nested lists. He's using the table to display the paw.

Comment: My bad, but he just could use CSS to display the paw. (Like in your answer @AdiUlici)

Comment: Can you remove the php and just show the html/css? PHP is not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code breaks in old versions of IE because you're putting a table in an anchor element.

You don't need a table to put the paw there. Just put it in CSS as a background image on the anchor and align it to right.

Something like:

```
a {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover {
    background: url("/i/paw.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 5px;
}
```

If you want to use the img element (so you can animate the opacity), you can do it better this way:

```
<a href='#'><img src='/i/paw.png' />Home</a>

.Nav a img { 
    float: right; 
    margin-right: 5px; 
    width: 20px; 
    opacity: 0; 
    /** transition and other stuff */ 
}
```

That's all you need. You can try it out and see if it breaks or not in IE.

Comment: This almost works except you can't adjust the opacity of just the image so it can't fade in like before. For now I'm just going to have it go from 0px to ~20px on hover.
It's also made the widths of my navbuttons go strange.

Comment: Okay, Ignore the thing about the widths (just because I didn't adjust the PHP as well as the CSS) However, the fade in thing still looks impossible with background-image

Comment: @Pete : See my updated answer. If you want to play with the opacity there's another way to keep the img element without using tables.

Comment: Seems to work well. Gunna keep it with the size transition and stick to your first answer though. Think it works better anyway! Good to know you can nest an img with text though. Thanks for the help